# How do I treat a fresh raw/scabbed nose injury on my cat?

Tags: cats, injury, first-aid

I noticed that one of my cats has a raw section of his nose, on the leather section. It appeared after a night where the two cats I have got into hissing/low growling during 'play'.

The cat is acting normal and doesn't seem to be in pain, but we cannot figure out what could have caused it since it does not look like a scratch, and it covers about 1/3 of his nose.

Is there any special considerations I should take to ensure that his nose doesn't get infected, or is this something that requires a vet visit?

Comment: is he ok now? same thing happened to my cat. did you take him to the vet?
looks like the leather section is torn.

Comment: @AmirK It ended up going away with some time. I kept an eye on it and made sure it didn't get any worse and eventually it healed up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First aid for a fresh (minor) cat injury is to clean the area with fresh water (no hydrogen peroxide). On noses, lips, and paw pads I'll apply either a 100% shea butter or vaseline (something that they could lick off and be okay).

Keep an eye on the injury for the next few days, if it becomes infected you'll need to take your cat to the vet. If your cat shows any sign of distress (panting, lethargy, hiding, crying), you need to go to the vet.